# How do you override the browser CSS defaults?

Tags: html, css

How do you override the browser defaults, for example, just the background color?

Comment: To clarify, I believe the OP is asking how to change the default style rules applied by the browser. For example, all browsers have the implicit rule `body { background-color: white; }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the browser. On [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) and [Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe), you can use the Stylish extension.

An example on Google Chrome:

1. Click the Stylish icon, and click *Write Style for*:

   [image]

   [image]
2. Add your desired CSS, name it, remove the *Applies to* specifier so that it applies to everything, and save it:

   [image]
3. Effect:

   [image]

Comment: Thanks, I just got confused of the "override" word thought you had to do something different to the usual changing the color through body

Comment: @John well, "override" was your choice of wording. O.o

Comment: It was the word on the document I read :P